# Which companions have romance options?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

SWTOR seems to have many romance options, and many opportunities to flirt with NPCs.

Listing all of the NPCs you can sleep with seems to be a unexpectedly large list outside the scope of this site, but which companions can you have a romance with?

Comment: You sir... are a pervert!

Comment: Provocative title, yes. But perhaps "What are the romantic options?" might be a gentler title?

Comment: Honestly, if my Imperial Agent is any indication, this list will be waaaay too long. Right at the start of Chapter 2, i've already got 8 notches on the bedpost including a noblemans wife and two Darths. Yes, the IA is James Bond in all his sleazy glory.

Comment: @Mufasa those are two different questions! *Romance* is reserved for companions, and then a limited subset thereof. But there's lots of NPC's happy to jump in the sack if you hit the **[Flirt]** button enough times.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest narrowing this down somewhat. As it stands, this question is borderline unanswerable by any one person without access to the games dialog files - and the time to have read them all- at least for several months.

Comment: I've edited the title for clarity and googlability. I know you are interested in more than just companions, but I think that caveat is fine in the body of the question (and not explicitly the title).

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't realize the list would be so large!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: True. "Romance with" and "have sex with" might be two different questions in RL. I haven't got far enough in the game to know if there is a difference b/w the two in this game. Though in Bioware's recent Mass Effect 2, the two were pretty close to synonymous from a gaming perspective.

Comment: Narrowed the scope of the question to just companions. Which meant I could answer it myself, now. Would eventually love to someday see the full list of NPCs though so I could make a character named Zapp Brannigan who roams the galaxy looking for love.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of who you can romance based on class ([source](http://www.hotrodacc.com/swtor/comp.html)):

### Jedi Knight

- Kira Carsen (F)
- Doc (M)

### Jedi Consular

- Zenith (M)
- Lt. Iresso (M)
- Tharan Cedrax (M)
- Nadia Grell (F)

### Sith Inquisitor

- Andronikus Revel (M)
- Ashara Zavros (F)

### Sith Warrior

- Vette (F)
- Jaesa Willsaam (F) (**dark side only**)
- Malavai Quinn (M)
- Lieutenant Pierce (M)

### Trooper

- Aric Jorgan (M)
- Elara Dorne (F)

### Smuggler

- Corso Riggs (M)
- Risha (F)
- Akavi Spaar (F)

### Bounty Hunter

- Mako (F)
- Torian Caldera (M)

### Imperial Agent

- Kaliyo Djannis (F)
- Vector Hyllis (M)
- Ensign Raina Temple (F)

Comment: Just a note, the genders listed here are the genders of the individuals *being romanced*, not the gender of the player character needed. At this time, all romance options are directly heterosexual. While BioWare has expressed a desire to include same sex romances at some nebulous point in the future, rumor is that LucasArts approval prevented them from making it into the game at launch.

Comment: Would be helpful to list which require Light / Dark Side to romance. I know  Jaesa requires dark side and requires you to turn *her* dark  side.

Comment: @Less, I remember fall out from an "all gay" guild in Starwars Galaxies, where the reason given was that, [canonically](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2009/4/29), there are no homosexuals in the Starwars universe.  Though there was *some* level of [retraction](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/bioware-rethinks-policy-on-homosexuality).

Comment: @tzenes In general, Bioware has been pretty progressive on these things - [at least recently](http://www.nomorelost.org/2011/03/25/straight-male-gamer-told-to-get-over-it-by-bioware/). My understanding is that this has been a point of contention between the devs and the Lucas folks.

Comment: @Less I believe the reason people from Lucas give is that it is not cannon.  With the exception of a [bug in kotor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Revan#Juhani)...

Comment: @tzenes Right. My point is that the first link you gave refers to a LucasArts statement on the matter, while the second is more of a BioWare forums policy that a CM made a... poor choice, to attempt to justify using the same Lucas argument.

Comment: @Less I believe the forum post was SOE (not Bioware), but regardless I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

## Jedi Knight

#### Male

- Kira Carsen (companion)
- Ranna Tao'Ven, after completing [The Face of the Enemy](http://swtorhub.com/db/quests/440027989409792)

## Republic Trooper

#### Male

- Sergeant Jaxo, after meeting her again at the end of the mission on Port Raga: [Optional: A Little R and R](http://www.torhead.com/mission/geKFAcF)

Comment: -1, One Per Answer style responses result in distorted voting patterns, an inability to 'accept' a definitive answer, and in general make a poor fit for the site.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Absolutely nothing stopping anyone else editing in additional answers, or providing a large list themselves. I personally am only aware of one instance of NPCs sleeping with you that happened to my toon over the weekend, seemed a shame to leave this question with no answers when I could add something.

Comment: Would you like me to convert this to community wiki, then?

Comment: I added some info and made it CW-style. Feel free to revert if this is not the direction we want to go.

Comment: The improvements are nice, but I'm keeping my downvote on this, as it no longer answers the question as written.

Answer (score -2):

Zenith is not a romance option.

Comment: Care to elaborate?